# Mic Input properties

Tags: android, ios

I'm developing audio app(iOS/Android), and I can't find nowhere information:

How can a app read or set the microphone gain?

Are audio Digital Signal Processing tools available for the headphone jack?

Also I realize that some manufacturers develop specific accessibility features (like mono sound mode, or sound balance (left - right) on samsung devices), but they don't provide any API to check or control this feature. When I turn on/off mono mode on Samsung GS3 in logs I see:

I/AudioHardwareTinyALSA( 1904): setParameters(toMono=0)

I/audio_wfd_hw( 1904): adev_set_parameters() toMono=0

So I guess this feature provided by samsung specific hardware driver. 
May be in some way is possible to get pointer to AudioHardwareTinyALSA an set mono on or off?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no API in Android for controlling the input volume (you can mute/unmute the mic during voice calls / VoIP, but that's about the level of control that you've got).

The mic gains are typically set by the OEMs as part of their acoustic tuning process, in order to optimize the performance for each use-case (speech recognition, camera recording, handset call, etc) for that particular product.

Mono/stereo recording *should* simply be decided by whether the app requests 1 or 2 channels for the recording. At least that's the way it has worked on every product I've worked on, as far as I can recall.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know about app request for 1 or 2 channels. I mean that samsung have an system option (mono/stereo), that override any app audio config requests. And there are no way to check or control this.